# getting previous balance before transaction date in ORACLE

Tags: java, oracle

I have a table (transactions) like this

```
ID   | Name  |   Unit  |Quantity_in|Quantity_out|transaction_date|
-----|-------| --------|-----------|------------|----------------|
100  |  aaaa |  packet |  100      |    0       |     02/07/2017 |
99   |  cccc |  packet |  70       |    0       |     20/06/2017 |
99   |  cccc |  packet |  0        |    20      |     22/07/2017 |
100  |  aaaa |  strip  |   0       |    30      |     05/07/2017 |
102  |  bbbb |  packet |  50       |    0       |     29/06/2017 |
```

I want to make a query to get the transaction and current balance between two days and at the same time to get previous balance before the date in the WHERE condition so I make the following query

*select d.ID, d.Name, d.Unit, **(select sum(tr.Quantity_in)- sum(tr.Quantity_out) from transactions tr where tr.transaction_date < 01/07/2017 and d.ID=tr.ID)** as Prev_bal,sum(d.Quantity_in), sum(d.Quantity_out),  Prev_bal +(sum(d.Quantity_in)- sum(d.Quantity_out)) as current_balance from transactions d
**where d.transaction_date between 01/07/2017 and 30/07/2017**
group by d.ID, d.Name, d.Unit*

but the result below of the query did not include the ID 102 because there is no transaction between the dates in the Where condition

```
ID  | Name | Unit   | Prev_bal | Quantity_in |  Quantity_out |Current_balance|
----|------| ------ |----------|-------------|---------------|---------------|    
100 |aaaa  |packet  |   0      |  100        |    30         |     70
----|----- |--------|----------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
99  |cccc  |packet  |   70     |  0          |    20         |     50        |
```

Can anyone help me to do the query that get the results of all IDs that have balance even if there is no transaction between the dates in the WHERE condition (like ID 102 in the table).
     I need to get the current balance (Current_balance) where the transaction_date between 2 dates and the previous balance (Prev_bal) for the IDs that have balances where the transaction_date < the dates in the where condition
Thanks in advance for your help.
The result should be like bellow

### ID  | Name | Unit   | Prev_bal | Quantity_in |  Quantity_out |Current_balance|

### 100 |aaaa  |packet  |   0      |  100        |    30         |     70

### 99  |cccc  |packet  |   70     |  0          |    20         |     50        |

102 |bbbb  |packet  |   50     |  0          |   0           |     50        |

---

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is table 'd'? And what is the output that you need? You have used SUM in your query but you haven't specified any grouping clause.

Comment: Thanks for notes
I adjust the query to add the sum and d

Comment: For Output, I need to get the current balance (Current_balance) where the transaction_date between 2 dates  and the previous balance (Prev_bal) for the IDs that have balances where the transaction_date < the dates in the where condition

Comment: And what happens when there are transactions after your date range?

Comment: no problem
I need just a report within date ranges only

Comment: You need to format the output in text editor before posting. It gets completely garbled otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how I thought about it.

Irrespective of the date range you provide, you still want every ID to be included in the result set. So there is no need to filter the rows out. So the problem is now just finding out the balance remaining at the end of a day. So for items within your date range the balance is the current balance and for items before your date range, its the previous balance (basically the last current balance).
Here is the query using Analytical functions in Oracle.

```
WITH dat
     AS (SELECT 100 AS id,
                'aaaa' AS name,
                'packet' AS unit,
                100 AS quantity_in,
                0 AS quantity_out,
                TO_DATE ('02/07/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS transaction_date
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 99 AS id,
                'cccc' AS name,
                'packet' AS unit,
                70 AS quantity_in,
                0 AS quantity_out,
                TO_DATE ('20/06/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS transaction_date
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 99 AS id,
                'cccc' AS name,
                'packet' AS unit,
                0 AS quantity_in,
                20 AS quantity_out,
                TO_DATE ('22/07/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS transaction_date
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 100 AS id,
                'aaaa' AS name,
                'strip' AS unit,
                0 AS quantity_in,
                30 AS quantity_out,
                TO_DATE ('05/07/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS transaction_date
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 102 AS id,
                'bbbb' AS name,
                'packet' AS unit,
                50 AS quantity_in,
                0 AS quantity_out,
                TO_DATE ('29/06/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS transaction_date
         FROM   DUAL)
SELECT id,
       name,
       unit,
       quantity_in,
       quantity_out,
       transaction_date,
       remaining_balance
FROM   (SELECT id,
               name,
               unit,
               quantity_in,
               quantity_out,
               balance,
               transaction_date,
               SUM (balance)
               OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY transaction_date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
                  AS remaining_balance,
               RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) AS rn
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       name,
                       unit,
                       quantity_in,
                       quantity_out,
                       quantity_in
                       - quantity_out
                          AS balance,
                       transaction_date
                FROM   dat))
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

It produces this result.

```
ID |NAME|UNIT   |  QUANTITY_IN|QUANTITY_OUT|TRANSACTION_DATE|REMAINING_BALANCE
99 |cccc|packet |            0|          20|       7/22/2017|               50
100|aaaa|strip  |            0|          30|        7/5/2017|               70
102|bbbb|packet |           50|           0|       6/29/2017|               50
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply
But if I have hundreds of IDs, that means I should repeat the select for each ID.
 The IDs in the table above is just an example not real data.

Comment: Also, the result should not be like your result.
for the right result please review my post for I added it at the end of the post recently

Comment: You don't have to repeat the select for each ID. The query will pickup all IDs in the table.

Comment: But that did not give the previous balance. It gives only the transactions and current balance

Comment: Isn't the previous balance same as the last current balance for items that are out of your date range?

Comment: No
to make the point clear, I have attached a zip file containing 4 files 1 -notes that explain what I need and the others are the real database table and queries please download the zip from the link bellow
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ushj382jj2qouh9/transactions.rar?dl=0

appreciate your help